# My wireless Epson printer appears offline, often. Why?

Tags: wireless-networking, printer, network-printer

I've got an Epson WF-3540 printer. It is connected to our network wirelessly. It used to not give us any problems until I had to reset the router. Now the printer hardly ever works for us, because it always appears to be offline. I've no idea why. And what is contradictory is I can easily get to the printer's website by navigating to its IP address, so it can't be offline.

So why does it appear to be offline to every machine in our house when it never was before?

Comment: If you reset the router then you should re-install the printer wireless connection.

Comment: I did, but that didn't help. I found I had to delete the printer from Devices and Printers. Then add it back in by using it's IP address. I'm reserving the printer's IP address on my router, so it won't change.

Comment: Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer). You might want to convert your comment into an answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found I had to delete the printer from Devices and Printers. Then add it back in by using it's IP address. I don't claim this will work for everyone experiencing this problem, but it is worth trying in case you encounter this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Per my answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1046206/why-does-my-printer-epson-printer-frequently-appear-offline), the problem is to do with the device driver binding the printer to a working network port. I have to repeatedly assign the printer to the WSD port and then back to the TCP port. Then it works...