# Why does my printer Epson printer frequently appear offline?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, printer, epson-workforce

I've asked about this before [My Wireless Epson printer appears offline often](https://superuser.com/questions/1030553/my-wireless-epson-printer-appears-offline-often-why), but the problem is bigger than I thought. It appears that my Epson WF-3540 printer always appears offline whenever we reboot any PC/laptop/whatever, cycle the power on the printer or cycle the power on our router. I don't understand why that is, but removing the printer and re-establishing it via it's IP address is getting very tedious. I've reserved the IP address in our router so that it will always have the same IP address, but that doesn't solve anything.

Why do we always have to remove and re-establish that printer? Why does it always appear offline whenever anything happens to any component of our network?

Comment: Which OS? IMHO the problem is in your computer (or router settings)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Epson WorkForce printer keeps power-cycling](http://superuser.com/questions/1153581/epson-workforce-printer-keeps-power-cycling)

Comment: This is probably a different issue than the proposed duplicate.  It pre-dates the problem Epson just created by almost a year and the symptoms are different.

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same problem. I found that a solution (so far) is that the printer ports were showing the printer bound to the WSD port and changing that to the standard TCP/IP port, as below, has solved the problem for now.

[image]

Comment: This hasn't totally fixed the problem, which is something to do with the port bindings. I have to repeatedly assign the printer to the WSD port and then back to the TCP port. Then it works...